# Smooth Rotation - Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to make a first person character controller and I am having an issue smoothing my look rotation. My `LookRotation` script takes my mouses input and uses it to rotate the character. I have used `Quaternion.Slerp()` in order to smooth my look rotation although there is an issue with using `Quaternion.Slerp()`. Once the desired rotation becomes larger than 180 degrees away from the current rotation it will just take the shorter route (the opposite way). The issue is in the last two lines of code. Does anyone have a method to prevent this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
#region Variables
// Sensitivity variables
[Range(0.0f, 10.0f)] public float horizontalSensitivity = 2.0f, verticalSensitivity = 2.0f;

// Smoothing Variables
[Range(0.0f, 30.0f)] public float smoothAmount = 5.0f;

// Character rotation variables
private Quaternion characterTargetRotation;
private Quaternion cameraTargetRotation;

public Transform character;
public Transform characterCamera;    
#endregion

private void Update()
{
    float horizontalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSensitivity;
    float verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSensitivity;

    characterTargetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, horizontalRotation, 0.0f);
    cameraTargetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-verticalRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    character.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_character.localRotation, characterTargetRotation, smoothAmount * Time.deltaTime);
    characterCamera.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_characterCamera.localRotation, cameraTargetRotation, smoothAmount * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `Quaternion.Slerp()` ? For basic rotation, I was thinking about using the simple and fast forward `Quaternion.Lerp()` method.

`Quaternion.Slerp()` spherically interpolates your rotation value and that may be the problem. 

I don't see either any reference to `transform.rotation` but I assume you do it later in the code.

Comment: @MadJlzz Thanks for the response, I probably should be using Quaternion.Lerp but that still yeilds the same issue as Quaternion.Slerp.

Comment: @MadJlzz Also I use `character.localRotation` & `characterCamera.localRotation` to alter the rotation (last two lines)

Comment: Well since I haven't Unity right next to me, I am not able to implement directly the behaviour you want but I've managed to do a tiny little script that do a rotation given a rotation speed and a damping value. [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/MadJlzz/7349975abec4821e6c64d4aaa089dceb) (the script is not tested but hopefully it will work).
It should help you manage your problem since the last thing you have to do is to calculate the desired rotation made by your mouse and apply it to your Game Object.

Edit: To alter rotation, you should alter the `transform.rotation` propriety.

Comment: @MadJlzz Thanks for taking your time to write a script, although it still has the same issue as mine, if the rotation amount is too much. Edit, the only difference between `transform.rotation` & `transform.localRotation` is that the `localRotation` will rotate the Game Object in accordance to the hierarchy of the Game Object.

Comment: Well I'm afraid you'll have to modify Lerp to fit your requirements. As of default, Lerp will always choose the "shorter route".

Comment: @jozza710 Okay, as Dunno said `Quaternion.Lerp()`will take the shortest route to the said rotation.
You can use a `Mathf.Lerp()`to get your next rotation value and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done using Quaternions and Lerp, I solved this using Euler angles.

```
    horizontalAngle += (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSensitivity);
    verticalAngle += (-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSensitivity);

    horizontalSmoothAngle = Mathf.Lerp(horizontalSmoothAngle, horizontalRotation, smoothAmount * Time.deltaTime);
    verticalSmoothAngle = Mathf.Lerp(verticalSmoothAngle , verticalRotation, smoothAmount * Time.deltaTime);

    horizontalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, smoothRotation ? horizontalSmoothAngle: horizontalAngle, 0);
    verticalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(smoothRotation ? verticalSmoothAngle : verticalAngle, 0, 0);
```

Using this method creates alternate issues you must deal with but using Quaternions and `Lerp` has an issue that cant be solved. As commented above, `Lerp` will always find the shortest distance. Eulers can go as high as you want (or more precisely as high as the data type allows) so it doesn't have this issue.

Although it is unlikely this will ever be an issue for a normal player if you keep adding to the angle, the data type in this case `float`, will eventually lose precision. To avoid this simply minus or add (dependent on whether the value is positive or negative) any multiple of 360 from the angle and the smoothed angle at a number high enough as to not effect the `Lerp`.

Getting the starting angle on the x axis using this method has some issues but is irrelevant to this question so anyone wanting to know how to do that will have to find an alternative source for the solution to that issue.